# Unity 3D - Cannot set the parent of my collided GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, game-physics

This bug is doing my head in and I can't figure it out!

I have an empty gun, and when I move it near the magazine it has a collide trigger that grabs the magazine, scales it and inserts it into the gun. This bit works fine. However in the code i also set the magazine parent to the gun and set the gravity to false and isKinematic to true - these bits do not happen. Therefore the magazine scales to the gun and then floats off into the distance and when I look in Unity it is not set to be a child of the gun and gravity and kinematic are both unchecked even though I clearly set these below. How is the magazine being scaled and positioned correctly but the parent and rigidbody edits are not being made?

Here is the code:

```
//THIS CLASS IS A CHILD OF THE GUN
public class GunBody : MonoBehaviour {

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
Debug.LogError("collision with well");

//check if the collision was with the magazine
if (collider.gameObject.name == "Magazine 1")
{
//reload the gun if it was
addClip(collider.gameObject);
}
}

public void addClip(GameObject magazine)
{
magazine.transform.parent = transform.parent; //DOES NOT WORK
magazine.transform.position = transform.parent.position;
magazine.transform.rotation = transform.parent.rotation;
magazine.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-89.96101f, 0f, 0f);
magazine.transform.localScale = new Vector3(14f, 20f, 20f);
magazine.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, -0.8215461f, 1.64772f);
magazine.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false; //DOES NOT WORK
magazine.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true; //DOES NOT WORK
}
```

Hopefully someone can spot what is going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you do `magazine.transform.parent = transform.parent;` you set your **script's parent** as a parent of magazine. I don't know how your code is organized, but are you sure you want to set magazine as a child of `GunBody's object` parent? And also maybe try using `magazine.transform.SetParent(this.transform)`.

Comment: The structure is like:  Gun contains body, magazine and handle. When I eject a magazine I set the parent to null so the magazine is no longer part of the gun. When I pick a new magazine up and it hits the collider I want to set the magazine OBJECT back into the gun. I guess what you are saying is this is NOT what I am currently doing?

Comment: The body is a child of Gun. So the parent of Body is the gun, so I am trying to set the magazine to be a child of the gun but it isn't working. Am I not doing something right? To clarify I don't want to set the scripts parent, I want to set the magazine objects parent which is what I thought I was doing as I am passing in collider.gameobject which is the magazine?

Comment: In this case you are doing it right, because this script sits in a child of your gun. Unfortunately problem is somewhere else and I don't know where. This code seems good to me. As I said you may play with `SetParent()`, but I doubt that it is the cause of your problem.
Do position and rotation work?

Comment: Yes this is what I don't get, the clip scales, rotates and positions into the gun. However gravity and kinematic are both unchecked and the magazine still is not under any parent at all. Could it be because I am getting the game object from the collider?

Comment: That crossed my mind too, but no, I don't think that having gameobject from collider affects it in any way, because it just passes a reference to your real gameobject. You can easily test it by using `Destroy(collider.gameobject)`.

Answer (score 0):

This scale and positioning problems come from not having (1,1,1) scale of gun. Try to put a gun and a magazine to another empty object.

Comment: Hey, they are on a different object. As mentioned the scaling and positioning work absolutely perfectly. But as soon as I move the gun the magazine floats away and when I check the object gravity is unchecked and so is kinematic, it is also not part of the gun. All 3 of these things I am clearly setting in the code, so I don't get why the scaling and positioning work but the other lines aren't?

Answer (score 0):

You can do
 magazine.transform.SetParent(transform.parent, false);

So it will be set according to position and orientation of Parent. No need to write First 3 lines of code to set Parent Position and Rotation.